# How to parse xml get from Ajax

Tags: jquery, xml-parsing

I have a table which is populated from my database.
My goal is to use update only the table when the user select another element from the list.

For that, I am using Ajax. I have my template with the HTML where I am using ajax:

```
{literal}
<script type="text/javascript">

function refreshToolPrivileges($Object)
{
$.ajax({
    url: '/ajax/user_management/refresh_tool_privileges'+$Object,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function(xml) {
        $(xml).find("Row").each(function(){

        });     
    }
});
}
</script>
{/literal}
```

Ajax is calling a php file where I am returning a formated xml file:

```
$format =
"\n\t<Row>
\t\t<group_id>{$fin_array['group_id']}</group_id>
\t\t<user_id>{$fin_array['user_id']}</user_id>
\t\t<Object>{$fin_array['Object']}</Object>
\t\t<Read>{$fin_array['Read']}</Read>
\t\t<Update>{$fin_array['Update']}</Update>
\t\t<Insert>{$fin_array['Insert']}</Insert>
\t\t<Delete>{$fin_array['Delete']}</Delete>
\t</Row>";

echo "<Result>" .$format. "\n</Result>";
```

Now, I don't know how to get the date from the returned XML and automaticaly update my table.

Here is the table:

```
<table width='700px' id="employeetable" class="tablesorter" style='table-layout:fixed;'>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Group Id</th>
        <th>User Id</th>
        <th>Object</th>
        <th>Read</th>
        <th>Update</th>
        <th>Insert</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    {foreach from=$privileges item=privilegesItem name=foo}
    <tr>
        <td>{$privilegesItem['group_id']}</td>
        <td>{$privilegesItem['user_id']}</td>
        <td>{$privilegesItem['Object']}</td>
        <td>{$privilegesItem['Read']}</td>
        <td>{$privilegesItem['Update']}</td>
        <td>{$privilegesItem['Insert']}</td>
        <td>{$privilegesItem['Delete']}</td>
    </tr>
    {/foreach}
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/ajax/user_management/refresh_tool_privileges_table/'+$Object,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function(xml) {
        $(xml).find("Row").each(function(){
            //alert('aaa');
            var group_id =$(this).find("group_id").text();
            var user_id=$(this).find("user_id").text();
            var Object=$(this).find("Object").text();
            var Read=$(this).find("Read").text();
            var Update=$(this).find("Update").text();
            var Insert=$(this).find("Insert").text();
            var Delete=$(this).find("Delete").text();

            $('tbody').remove();
            // jquery create a new tbody and insert aftre thead
            $('#employeetable').append(
                    '<tbody>'+
                    '<tr>'+
                        '<td>'+group_id+'</td>'+
                        '<td>'+user_id+'</td>'+
                        '<td>'+Object+'</td>'+
                        '<td>'+Read+'</td>'+
                        '<td>'+Update+'</td>'+
                        '<td>'+Insert+'</td>'+
                        '<td>'+Delete+'</td>'+
                    '</tr>'+
                    '</tbody>');



        });     
    }
});
```

I am removing the body and then creating a new one with the new variables.